# Android: How to remove black line below the GridView

Tags: android, gridview, padding

I have a GridView. I have added some paddingBottom for the view. When I scroll my GridView there is a blackish line that is seen on the border of gridview and bottom padding. How do I get rid of this blackish line?

The gridview xml code is as follows:

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/slot_gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="507dp"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="31dp"
             />
```

Comment: post your XML file that has the Grid View in it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

for disable black strip.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:scrollingCache="false"
```